# Jenkins pipeline BuildDiscarderProperty

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to utilize BuildDiscarderProperty option with our jenkins job template. But currently it is working only with properties function which is not favoring with usage of job template. Could someone help us to configure BuildDiscarderProperty option without using properties function?
Thanks

Comment: i don't follow why properties are not playing nicely with a "job template" since i'm not sure what job templates are. are you using a plugin to implement "job templates"? which one? are you using a Jenkinsfile? if so, can you post it?

Comment: usually when you create job based of any job template, it will show link to  template and if you click config, it will provide option to update Attributes defined at job template. But if you have properties defined, after fist execution of job, link to template will be missing and also if you click configure, it will be like a stand alone pipeline job. So any future changes to template wont be available for these jobs.

Comment: you will be a message like below during execution. WARNING: The properties step will remove all JobPropertys currently configured in this job, either from the UI or from an earlier properties step.
This includes configuration for discarding old builds, parameters, concurrent builds and build triggers.
WARNING: Removing existing job property ''

Comment: i don't think it's possible to specify "discard old builds" in a Jenkinsfile without using properties. feel free to not respond to this, but i'm curious what the templates are buying you given all of the job configurations are in source control (Jenkinsfiles and shared libraries)?

Comment: I saw this at cloudbess site. But trying to understand Declarative Pipeline Syntax - https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000237071-How-do-I-set-discard-old-builds-for-a-Multi-Branch-Pipeline-Job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Used General job definition at Groovy Template for pipeline. It is not breaking anything but just deleting old builds

```
<flow-definition>
<properties>
  <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
  <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
    <daysToKeep>365</daysToKeep>
    <numToKeep>30</numToKeep>
    <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
    <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
  </strategy>
  </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
  <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
</org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
</properties>

</flow-definition>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, here's a full declarative pipeline that discards old builds:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '200'))
  }
  stages {
    stage ('build') {
      steps {
        sh 'ls'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I assert that templates are deprecated. Sound right? :)

Comment: This option worked but the job properties reset and removed link to job template :( Working exactly same as like using properties function. 
                                                                                                
  WARNING: The properties step will remove all JobPropertys currently configured in this job, either from the UI or from an earlier properties step.
This includes configuration for discarding old builds, parameters, concurrent builds and build triggers.
WARNING: Removing existing job property ''
WARNING: Removing existing job property 'Build triggers'

Comment: ya, i wouldn't expect it to work differently from a scripted pipeline in that regard. my assertion (that i'm not certain is true) was that templates are not relevant/necessary in a pipelines-as-code world.